# Add a JScrollPane to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane

I have a question in relation to adding components to a Java frame.

I have a JPanel with two buttons and also a JScrollPane that has a JTable added to it. I am wanting to add both these to a JFrame.

I can add either the JPanel to the JFrame, or the JScrollPane to the JFrame and they display correctly. I am having trouble adding them both to the JFrame and displaying them both.

Is there something related to JFrames that do not allow this? Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

The problem is not with the layout (at least I do not think that it is), the problem is that the ScrollPane is not displaying correctly.
Here is the code:

```
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    guiPanel.add(scrollPane, gbc);
    guiPanel.add(buttons, gbc);        
    
    guiFrame.add(guiPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    guiFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. 3) Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`. 4) For frame positioning, you cannot go by `setLocationByPlatform(true)`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556) for demo. ..

Comment: .. 5) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 3):

By Default, JFrame has Borderlayout. BorderLayout have five flags. When you will not specify any flag, It will add you component to frame with center flag. Center flag give all space to component which is added with center flag, if no other flag is specified with component. for more information on border layout, visit following link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

You can add both by using following statement:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

frame.add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

frame.add(new JScrollpane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

GridBagLayout is not good for this situation. With lesser code you can get desired Code.

```
JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
pnlButton.add(button1);
pnlButton.add(button2);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(pnlButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

If you want to go only with Gridbaglayout. Then you will have to set weightX, weightY, gridwidth and other properties like that

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
gbc.weightx=1.0;
gbc.weighy=1.0;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
guiPanel.add(scrollPane, gbc);
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE
guiPanel.add(buttons, gbc);        
guiFrame.add(guiPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
guiFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Please try and let me know, if it does not work, I will send complete code with GridBaglayout.